# Sum of two maximal ideal is necesarily maximal ideal?

Tags: ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Sum of two prime ideal is not necessarily a prime ideal. Example in the ring $\mathbb{C}[x, y]$ with prime ideals $P = (x^2 + y^2 − 1)$ and $Q = (x)$, but $P+Q$ is not prime ideal. My question is sum of two maximal ideal is necessarily a maximal ideal?

Comment: The sum of two distinct maximal ideals is (a) an ideal and (b) strictly contains each of the two maximal ideals you started with. So what can you conclude ...

Comment: @user60589 My comment is just that, a comment - and an invitation to reflect on the meaning of "maximal" here. I didn't want to complete an answer, because actually the question here reflects a situation which comes up more than once in proving useful theorems, and it seems helpful to me to think about the situation a bit the first time that you meet it, rather than just being told what the answer is and thinking it is trivial and forgetting about it. Rather understand why maximality is a useful property, and begin to understand how it can be deployed.

Comment: @MarkBennet Sorry

Answer (score 7):

If $M, N$ are two distinct maximal ideals then there exists $x \in M$ wlog such that $x \notin N$.  This means that $x \in M + N$ and since $N \subset M + N \subset A$ and $M + N \neq N$ we must have $M + N = A$ the whole ring.